# How to improving a dictionary self-search comparison and merger

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, time

I need to compare a dictionary to values to find all the values that match and add them out. The problem is that I have really large dictionaries and my code is really slow. Is there a better way to do this or to improve my code timing?

```
import itertools
import copy

Dic = {
    0: ['-1','A','B','p','r'],
    1: ['-','q','p','r'],
    2: ['-1','K','q','p','r'],
    3: ['+','q','p','r'],
    4: ['1','B','q','p','r'],
    5: ['-','K','q','p','r'],
}

def S_Sing(SX_Sing,SY_Sing):
       if SX_Sing=='+' or SX_Sing=='-':
          XX_L=[SX_Sing]
       elif SX_Sing!='+' or SX_Sing!='-':
          XX_L=SX_Sing
       if SY_Sing=='+' or SY_Sing=='-':
          YY_L=[SY_Sing]
       elif SY_Sing!='+' or SY_Sing!='-':
          YY_L=SY_Sing    
       if XX_L==['+'] or XX_L==['-']:
             XX_L.append('1')
       if YY_L==['+'] or YY_L==['-']:
             YY_L.append('1')            
       Final=int(''.join(XX_L))+int(''.join(YY_L))
       Sum_Final=str(Final)
       return Sum_Final 


def Comp_Dict_Itself(DicX1):
        D_itself_F={}
        D_clone= copy.deepcopy(DicX1) 
        Dic_to_Lista=[]

        for k,v in D_clone.iteritems():
          Dic_to_Lista.append(v)
        for a, b in itertools.combinations(Dic_to_Lista, 2):
          if a[:1]!='0' and b[:1]!='0' :
            if a[1:]==b[1:]:

                S_Final=S_Sing(a[:1],b[:1]) 
                if S_Final==0:
                    b[:]='0'
                    a[:]='0'
                if S_Final!=0:
                    b[0]='0'
                    a[0]=S_Final    


        somelist_F = [x for x in Dic_to_Lista if x[0]!='0']
        for pos, item in enumerate(somelist_F ):  
            if item[0]!='0':
                D_itself_F[pos]= item 
        return D_itself_F

print(Comp_Dict_Itself(Dic))
```

Output:

```
{0: ['-1', 'A', 'B', 'p', 'r'], 1: ['-2', 'K', 'q', 'p', 'r'], 2: ['1', 'B', 'q', 'p', 'r']}
```

What the code does is  first check each value, in order to add the values the `v[1:]` values need to be identical for the keys that are taken in account e.g. key A and B. `v[0]` is just a constant that represents the number of times the list is repeated. Then `v[0]` depending on its sign and value will add or subtract e.g. `vA[0]='1'` or `vA[0]='+'`  and `vB[0]='-1'` or `vB[0]='-'`  then the new `vA[0]` and `vB[0]` will be `0` but if `vA[0]=1` and `vB[0]=1` then the new values will be `vA[0]=2` and `vB[0]=0`. Then the key with values `0` will be removed

Comment: can you give an example of two (smaller) dictionaries and the results you expect?

Comment: One of the dictionaries is in the code, Dic. and the result I expect is the output I put after the code. Wha the code does is that

Comment: What I'm saying is that you have the condition `if a[:1] != '0' and b[:1] != '0'`. Currently this condition is *always* true, so it's useless. You probably wanted to do something like `if a[0] != 0 and b[0] != 0`.

Comment: Ah, I just saw that you are using `iteritems` but then you are appending only the *values*. Why don't you just to: `dic_to_lista  = list(dic.values())` instead? If you are doing python2 you don't even have to call `list`.

Comment: Also, in `Dic`, what's the meaning of the keys?

Comment: I am running the for a, b  in combinations( ...,2) on the list I made from the original dictionary (Dic_to_Lista). I have run this piece of code and I don't get that error that is weird. How should I declare my loop?

Comment: The keys are from the sample label  so I don't really care if the keys change since is just the experiment repetition. On the other hand,  the values are the result of the experiment and that is what is important for me. The values in a sequence of  amino acids abbreviations for example  ['-1', 'A', 'B', 'p', 'r'] Just meets that for that set of data, the Adenine bi para rectus structure was reduce one unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have tried to understand your code and it seems that you are doing the equivalent of the following, which I hope is simpler, clearer and at least a bit more efficient:

```
import itertools as it


def sign_to_num(val):
    if val == '+':
        return 1
    elif val == '-':
        return -1
    return int(val)


def item_sum(left_val, right_val):
    return sign_to_num(left_val) + sign_to_num(right_val)


def comp_dict_itself(d):
    values = [list(v) for v in d.values()]
    for a, b in it.combinations(values, 2):
        if a[0] != '0' != b[0] and a[1:] == b[1:]:
            a[0] = str(item_sum(a[0], b[0]))
            b[0] = '0'

    return dict(enumerate(v for v in values if v[0] != '0'))
```

Notes:

- The comparison in your code: `if a[:1] != '0' and b[:1] != '0'` is useless because the condition is **always** true. That's because `a` and `b` are two `list`s so `a[:1] == ['0']` or `a[:1] == ['+']`. In every case they are different from a `str`.

  I have changed that to `a[0] != '0' and b[0] != '0'` which can be simplified to `a[0] != '0' != b[0]`.
- It doesn't really make sense to have a `dict` with integer keys, especially if these keys are consecutive. You could simply use a `list`.
- `dict`s aren't ordered so the list of `values` need not have the order corresponding to the values of the keys.
- There's no need to use `deepcopy` to first create a new `dict` and then extract the list of values. See how I build `values`.

Comment: You a right the condition needed to be if a[0]!='0' and b[0]]!='0' : instead of the other one. The reason why I have a dictionary is because I got the dictionaries for an equipment but I can certainly change the dictionaries to a list.  I will run this and check the timing now.

Comment: @user3671704 You should probably profile the code. There's a module [`profile`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/profile.html) that not only gives you the timing of the whole thing but also tells you the number of calls to the different functions used and the time they take, so that you can see exactly which part of your function is taking the most time.

Comment: This is the timing result:

10  149.088   14.909  150.664   15.066 Amino.py:647(Comparin_Dict_Itself)

10   42.446    4.245   42.543    4.254 Amino.py:666(comp_dict_itself)

 There was a huge improvement! I was wondering how can you use the same idea in the cases of 2 dictionary : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140063/a-better-and-faster-way-for-this-code-to-compare-2-dictionaries-really-large

Answer (score 0):

I Played around with this code and using the previous answer I find a faster solution:

```
def sign_to_num(val):
if val == '+':
    return 1
elif val == '-':
    return -1
return int(val)


def item_sum(left_val, right_val):
    return sign_to_num(left_val) + sign_to_num(right_val)


def comp_dict_itself2(d):
    values = [list(v) for v in d.values()]
    results = {}
    for item in values:
        key = (" ".join(str(x) for x in item[1:])) #Dict_A_R[]=
        if key in results: 
            results[key][0]= str(item_sum(results[key][0], item[0]))
        else:   
            results[key] = item
    DicFinal={}
    for pos, item in enumerate(results ):  
                 DicFinal[pos]= results [item] 
    return DicFinal
```

The first two functions are from Bakuriu's solution the new  comp_dict_itself2 function use create a dictionary and add the number of repetitions that are found.

For the Dictionary I am running these is the profiles:

```
  ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)

   18   58.947    3.275   59.045    3.280 Test_a.py:666(comp_dict_itself)

   18    0.193    0.011    0.491    0.027 Test_a.py:675(comp_dict_itself2)
```